# Delete Cookies from Webbrowser control in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with facebook and google logout.  My scenario  is when user first time login with facebook or google for particular site.(using clint api, it will redirect to their own web browser). then it will show the login page . after successfully logout if again login with facebook or google i m trying it's not showing the login page , it directly shows the login success message.(because webbrowser history already there, and i am not able to delete the history) so in this situation multiple user can't login with facebook or google.

have anyone idea? how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WP7 you'll have to use `InvokeScript` and javascript to logout and/or get rid of cookies required by different services like FB and Google.  Fiddler comes in handy for this.

If I remember correctly, for Google you'll have to watch for specific URL's and cancel navigation, run `InvokeScript` and continue navigation.

I worked on a project that accessed different providers and this was the solution we were able to get working.

On WP8 there is a method to clear cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding out if there is an OAuth or API url for logging the user out such as

```
m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=(url encoded login page)
```

to navigate the user to.

Comment: i am not using any third party SDK?

Comment: I think @Derek has a better approach.